# Is it worth putting a business logic layer on top of Linq to SQL?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I feel like I may be doing something dumb.

I've had a Linq to SQL library running for years, and used it in several applications that use the same database.  There are a bunch of things I'm not terribly happy with though, and I just got a new project.  I was thinking that it would be helpful to put a business logic layer between the application and the Linq to SQL library.  The problem is the more I design it out, the more it looks like I'm just trying to implement something that looks just like  Linq to SQL.

For instance, I decided that the application should have a single entry point to the business logic.  So that entry point (I called it MCP) has a property for class in the system, and this property has a "list" (probably IQueryable) that contains all the objects from the corresponding table.  Which starts sounding, and looking, a lot like a Linq to SQL data context...plus I feel like having an extra object/accessor wrapped around every existing object is a ton of extra typing just to hide the "real" objects.

So because of that I'm a little afraid I'm just doing a bad re-implementation of what I already have.

On the flip-side, I am hopefully improving on how everything works.  For instance ensuring that an object has one logical responsibility, rather than it being a way of accessing anything else in the system.  (For instance a CarCP might have a method for AddDriver(Person p) but Person wouldn't necessarily have methods to go back to CarCP.)

So maybe it is better to have this middle layer, but I'm just designing it badly?